# How to draw a stretched/pulled/conical spiral

Tags: vector, shapes, diagram

I'm trying to redraw a diagram, and I'm having difficulty recreating the base spiral:
[image: Diagram/Spiral]

I need to make the concentric spiral part.

Can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE! What you're trying to do is draw bezier curves...knowing that term will help you as you search online if no one gives you an answer here right away.

Comment: "conical spiral" is another search term that might help. One quick thing you could try (not tested): draw one segment as a path with a stroke, copy, paste, scale up by X%, align, join paths, paste again, scale up by X% twice, align, join to the two existing segments, paste, scale up by X% 3 times... etc

Answer (score 7):

It is easy as usual! 
For that i will use Illustrator CS5.

1) Take a "Spiral Tool"

[image]

2) Now click on the screen and set some options for the spiral creation. Then click "OK"

[image]

3) A new spiral will be drawn:

[image]

4) Now transform the spiral:

[image]

5) Rotate and scale:

[image]

6) It will be look like this:

[image]

7) Take a "Reshape Tool" (the magic begins :)

[image]

8) Select the lowest node of the spiral and drag it to bottom:

[image]

9) Thats all:

[image]

Comment: That's exactly the sort of thing I'm looking for... unfortunately its using Adobe Illustrator which costs me money or requires me to seek out pirate copies.  Do you know how to do this in something free like inkscape or gimp?

Comment: @E_L Oww, sorry no :(

Comment: @mast0r all the steps excepts step 9 is available on inkscape. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is an old question, but thought it worthwhile posting a method for Inkscape 1.0 since the OP mentioned doing this in something other than Adobe Illustrator.

1. Draw a rectangle like this, and then do *Extentions > Render > Parametric Curves*, and use the settings shown below.

[image]

2. Rotate and squash the spring a bit, then add a Perspective/Envelope Path Effect, set the type to "Envelope deformation"
3. Using the Edit Paths by Nodes Tool (N) click and drag the control points to distort it.

[image]

4. Convert back to a path using *Path > Object to Path*
5. Select and break some nodes
6. Do *Path > Break apart*
7. Add arrow markers in the Fill and Stroke panel

[image]

Comment: Why not do this all in same formula?

Comment: @joojaa - That would be nice, if only I knew the formula to achieve it. LOL.

Comment: Replace 3.2 and 2 with (3.2+0.32*t) and (2+0.2*t)  where 0.32 and 0.2 are expansion multipliers and 3.2 and 2 are initial sizes

Comment: Yeah -  also just changing the Y function to 1-2*cos(t)*t/8 seems to work quite well

Comment: If you want the  height of each spiral to stay same and not scale. Anyway a more in depth explanatiom can be found https://bitbucket.org/joojaa/jooillustratorscripts/wiki/Documentation/jooGraphFunction

Comment: @joojaa Nice link!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111013/discussion-between-joojaa-and-billy-kerr).